# How to initialize Variant pvarVal

Tags: c++

I have the below code in which I am calling VariantInit method for variant.pvarval, because I am going to store varaint in the another variant called pval. So before storing value into `pVal->pvarVal`, I am calling `VariantInit` for `pVal->pvarVal`. But the call `VariantInit(pVal->pvarVal)` is crashing.

```
void Function(VARIANT FAR* pVal)
    { 

       VariantInit(pVal);
       VariantInit(pVal->pvarVal);

       pVal->vt = VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF ;

        __int64 biNewVal =  // Some logic here
        pVal->pvarVal->vt = VT_CY;
        pVal->pvarVal->cyVal.int64 = biNewVal;

    }


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VARIANT var;    
    Function(&var);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must making `pVal->pvarVal` point somewhere before trying to initialize the space it is pointing to...

Comment: @M.M How to make pVal->pvarVal point ?

Comment: write `pVal->pvarVal = x;` where `x` is some memory you have allocated for a variant..  IDK what the recommended way to do this is though (that will be compatible with `VariantClear`).

Answer (score 0):

From Online Help

> The VariantInit function initializes the VARIANTARG by setting the vt member to VT_EMPTY.

This init function does not initialize the pvarVal to any valid pointer to variant
So in your Code you have 
 pVal->vt = VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF ;

```
    __int64 biNewVal =  // Some logic here
    pVal->pvarval=new VARIANT;
    pVal->pvarVal->vt = VT_CY;
    pVal->pvarVal->cyVal.int64 = biNewVal;
```

Doing so it will work

Comment: doing this way, the `main` must be sure to do `delete var.pvarVal;` before calling `VariantClear`